# How can I pass an argument (via highlighting) to a shell command while also passing the filename as an argument?

Tags: shell-command

Im attempting to run a perl script on a buffer which will rearrange/edit the contents. I want to highlight a string and let that be my input as well as the buffer or file.

Currently I can come close. I know `C-x h M-| shell command` will pass the buffer to STDIN which can be used. But it doesnt give me the ability to also pass a string.

Is there a way to pass both?

Comment: Here are some links that may be helpful -- **Shell Arguments**:  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Shell-Arguments.html -- **Creating an Asynchronous Process**:  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Asynchronous-Processes.html